# Can I update an HDFStore?

Tags: python, pandas, hdf5, hdfstore

Consider the following `hdfstore` and dataframes `df` and `df2`

```
import pandas as pd

store = pd.HDFStore('test.h5')
```

---

```
midx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([range(2), list('XYZ')], names=list('AB'))
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(C=range(6)), midx)

df

     C
A B   
0 X  0
  Y  1
  Z  2
1 X  3
  Y  4
  Z  5
```

---

```
midx2 = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([range(2), list('VWX')], names=list('AB'))
df2 = pd.DataFrame(dict(C=range(6)), midx2)

df2

     C
A B   
0 V  0
  W  1
  X  2
1 V  3
  W  4
  X  5
```

---

I want to first write `df` to the store.

```
store.append('df', df)

store.get('df')

     C
A B   
0 X  0
  Y  1
  Z  2
1 X  3
  Y  4
  Z  5
```

---

At a later point in time I will have another dataframe that I want to update the store with.  I want to overwrite the rows with the same index values as are in my new dataframe while keeping the old ones.

When I do

```
store.append('df', df2)

store.get('df')

     C
A B   
0 X  0
  Y  1
  Z  2
1 X  3
  Y  4
  Z  5
0 V  0
  W  1
  X  2
1 V  3
  W  4
  X  5
```

This isn't at all what I want.  Notice that `(0, 'X')` and `(1, 'X')` are repeated.  I can manipulate the combined dataframe and overwrite, but I expect to be working with a lot data where this wouldn't be feasible.

How do I update the store to get?

```
     C
A B   
0 V  0
  W  1
  X  2
  Y  1
  Z  2
1 V  3
  W  4
  X  5
  Y  4
  Z  5
```

You'll see that For each level of `'A'`, `'Y'` and '`Z'` are the same,  `'V'` and `'W'` are new, and `'X'` is updated.

What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: can you work with normal (not multiindex) indexes?

Comment: Yes... my real data has multiindex, but if you show something with single index, I'm happy with that.

Comment: OK, i'll need some time for preparing a demo...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Idea:** remove matching rows (with matching index values) from the HDF first and then append `df2` to HDFStore.

**Problem:** I couldn't find a way to use `where="index in df2.index"` for multi-index indexes.

**Solution:** first convert multiindexes to normal ones:

```
df.index = df.index.get_level_values(0).astype(str) + '_' + df.index.get_level_values(1).astype(str)

df2.index = df2.index.get_level_values(0).astype(str) + '_' + df2.index.get_level_values(1).astype(str)
```

this yields:

```
In [348]: df
Out[348]:
     C
0_X  0
0_Y  1
0_Z  2
1_X  3
1_Y  4
1_Z  5

In [349]: df2
Out[349]:
     C
0_V  0
0_W  1
0_X  2
1_V  3
1_W  4
1_X  5
```

make sure that you use `format='t'` and `data_columns=True` (this will index save index and index **all** columns in the HDF5 file, allowing us to use them in the `where` clause) when you create/append HDF5 files:

```
store = pd.HDFStore('d:/temp/test1.h5')
store.append('df', df, format='t', data_columns=True)
store.close()
```

now we can first remove those rows from the HDFStore with matching indexes:

```
store = pd.HDFStore('d:/temp/test1.h5')

In [345]: store.remove('df', where="index in df2.index")
Out[345]: 2
```

and append `df2`:

```
In [346]: store.append('df', df2, format='t', data_columns=True, append=True)
```

Result:

```
In [347]: store.get('df')
Out[347]:
     C
0_Y  1
0_Z  2
1_Y  4
1_Z  5
0_V  0
0_W  1
0_X  2
1_V  3
1_W  4
1_X  5
```

Comment: Thank you very much!  I learned a lot there.  I've got some ideas now.  I'll report back.

Comment: @piRSquared, glad if it helps. Yes, please give a short feedback about your final solution. This will also help those having the same issue...

Comment: There is an issue with the `where="index in df.index"` syntax. See Pandas [bug#17567](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/17567) for explanation and workaround.